# Windows api AES256 Decryption

Tags: winapi, encryption, wincrypt

I'm not very good with cryptography api's and im trying to encrypt and decrypt a binary file. I put together the following code to encrypt a file and store it back to a file and it works,

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool EncryptAES256(char* data, DWORD dataSize, const char* key, DWORD keySize) {
    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv = NULL;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = NULL;
    HCRYPTKEY hKey = NULL;
    DWORD dwMode = CRYPT_MODE_CBC;

    // Create a cryptographic provider context handle.
    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptAcquireContext failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Create a hash object of the key.
    if (!CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptCreateHash failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    if (!CryptHashData(hHash, (const BYTE*)key, keySize, 0)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptHashData failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    // Derive a symmetric key from the hash.
    if (!CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProv, CALG_AES_256, hHash, 0, &hKey)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptDeriveKey failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    // Set encryption mode to CBC
    if (!CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_MODE, (BYTE*)&dwMode, 0)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptSetKeyParam failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    // Apply PKCS7 padding to the data buffer
    int padding = 16 - (dataSize % 16);
    for (int i = 0; i < padding; ++i) {
        data[dataSize + i] = padding;
    }
    dataSize += padding;

    // Encrypt the data using AES 256.
    if (!CryptEncrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, (BYTE*)data, &dataSize, dataSize * 2)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptEncrypt failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    // Print the encrypted data
    std::cout << "Encrypted Data: ";
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        printf("%02x", (unsigned char)data[i]);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Clean up resources.
    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);

    return true;
}

int main() {
    HANDLE hF = CreateFileA("C:\\temp\\test.bin",
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
    if (hF == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "ERR CreateFileA failed" << std::endl;
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    long r_dwSize = GetFileSize(hF, NULL);
    LPVOID lpbase = VirtualAlloc(NULL, r_dwSize * 2, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    DWORD dwReadBytes = 0;
    BOOL r_read = ReadFile(hF, lpbase, r_dwSize, &dwReadBytes, NULL);
    if (!r_read) {
        std::cout << "ERR ReadFile failed" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hF);
        VirtualFree(lpbase, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }


    std::cout << "Original Data: ";
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        printf("%02x", (unsigned char)((char*)lpbase)[i]);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Create a new file to write the encrypted data
    HANDLE hEncryptedFile = CreateFileA("C:\\temp\\encrypted_output.bin",
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, // Creates a new file; if the file exists, it's truncated
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    if (hEncryptedFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "ERR CreateFileA for encrypted file failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hF);
        VirtualFree(lpbase, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    // Encrypt the data
    std::string key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"; // Replace with your 32-byte key in hexadecimal format
    bool encryptionResult = EncryptAES256((char*)lpbase, dwReadBytes, key.c_str(), key.size() / 2); // Divide by 2 for hexadecimal bytes

    if (encryptionResult) {
        std::cout << "Encryption successful!" << std::endl;
        // Write the encrypted data to the new file
        DWORD dwBytesWritten;
        BOOL writeResult = WriteFile(hEncryptedFile, lpbase, dwReadBytes, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
        if (writeResult) {
            std::cout << "Encrypted data written to encrypted_output.bin" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Error writing encrypted data to file with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Encryption failed!" << std::endl;
    }

    // Close the handles and free the allocated memory
    CloseHandle(hEncryptedFile);
    CloseHandle(hF);
    VirtualFree(lpbase, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    return 0;

}
```

but when i want to decrypt it i keep getting `2148073477` error code from `CryptDecrypt` function, below is the code for decryption,

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool DecryptAES256(char* data, DWORD& dataSize, const char* key, DWORD keySize) {
    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv = NULL;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = NULL;
    HCRYPTKEY hKey = NULL;
    DWORD dwMode = CRYPT_MODE_CBC;

    // Create a cryptographic provider context handle.
    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptAcquireContext failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Create a hash object of the key.
    if (!CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptCreateHash failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    if (!CryptHashData(hHash, (const BYTE*)key, keySize, 0)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptHashData failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    // Derive a symmetric key from the hash.
    if (!CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProv, CALG_AES_256, hHash, 0, &hKey)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptDeriveKey failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    // Set decryption mode to CBC
    if (!CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_MODE, (BYTE*)&dwMode, 0)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptSetKeyParam failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    // Decrypt the data using AES 256.
    if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, (BYTE*)data, &dataSize)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: CryptDecrypt failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    // Remove PKCS7 padding
    BYTE padValue = data[dataSize - 1];
    if (padValue >= 1 && padValue <= 16) {
        dataSize -= padValue;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Error: Invalid PKCS7 padding value" << std::endl;
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        return false;
    }

    // Clean up resources.
    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);

    return true;
}


int main() {
    // Open the encrypted file
    HANDLE hEncryptedFile = CreateFileA("C:\\temp\\encrypted_output.bin",
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    if (hEncryptedFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Unable to open encrypted file. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Get the size of the encrypted file
    DWORD encryptedFileSize = GetFileSize(hEncryptedFile, NULL);

    // Allocate memory to read the encrypted data
    std::vector<BYTE> encryptedData(encryptedFileSize);
    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    if (!ReadFile(hEncryptedFile, encryptedData.data(), encryptedFileSize, &dwBytesRead, NULL)) {
        std::cerr << "Error reading encrypted data from file. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hEncryptedFile);
        return -1;
    }

    CloseHandle(hEncryptedFile);

    // Decrypt the data
    std::string key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    DWORD dataSize = dwBytesRead; // Initial data size equals the read size

    if (DecryptAES256(reinterpret_cast<char*>(encryptedData.data()), dataSize, key.c_str(), key.size() / 2)) {
        std::cout << "Decryption successful!" << std::endl;

        // Create a new file to write the decrypted data
        HANDLE hDecryptedFile = CreateFileA("C:\\temp\\decrypted_output.exe",
            GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            NULL,
            CREATE_ALWAYS,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);

        if (hDecryptedFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            std::cerr << "Error: Unable to create decrypted file. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        // Write the decrypted data to the new file
        DWORD dwBytesWritten;
        if (!WriteFile(hDecryptedFile, encryptedData.data(), dataSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL)) {
            std::cerr << "Error writing decrypted data to file. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Decrypted data written to decrypted_output.exe" << std::endl;
        }

        CloseHandle(hDecryptedFile);
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Decryption failed!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

unfortunately i cannot figure out how to fix it! I got pretty confused with padding other details i hope i can get some help from you guys.

thanks

Comment: Why would you assume that decrypt takes the key in a format different from that of encrypt?

Comment: Error code 2148073477 (0x80090005) is an `HRESULT` for Security API error 5, aka `NTE_BAD_DATA`. Which function is actually failing with this error?

Comment: I changed the key format in decrypt to match encrypt function. I still get the same error

Comment: @RemyLebeau, this is the exact error i get as output, Error: CryptDecrypt failed with error code 2148073477
Decryption failed!

Comment: If the key is a block cipher key, the data is padded to a multiple of the block size of the cipher.
If the cipher is operating in a chaining mode, the next CryptDecrypt operation resets the cipher's feedback register to the KP_IV value of the key.
If the cipher is a stream cipher, the next CryptDecrypt call resets the cipher to its initial state.
I suggest you should check the size of dwDataLen and dwBlockLen. Refer to the sample:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program-decrypting-a-file

Comment: @David Have you got any updates about this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You are handling the padding incorrectly. For a block cipher mode like CBC the default padding of *wincrypt* is PKCS#7. This can be verified with [`CryptGetKeyParam`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgetkeyparam) in conjunction with `KP_PADDING` (and changed with [`CryptSetKeyParam`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptsetkeyparam)). Therefore, your custom padding is to be removed (in encryption and decryption).
The length of the ciphertext (which is needed e.g. for writing the ciphertext to the file) is stored in [`pdwDataLen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptencrypt#parameters) after encryption with [`CryptEncrypt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptencrypt).
If this is considered, decryption of the generated ciphertext works on my machine (assuming encryption and decryption use the same key, which has already been pointed out in the comments).

*Security:* Note that CBC uses an IV and that for each encryption a *random* IV should be generated. The IV is not secret. Therefore, it is usually concatenated with the ciphertext so that it is available during decryption.
If you don't generate an IV, a zero IV is used by default (consisting of 16 0x00 values; this can be verified with `CryptGetKeyParam()` in conjunction with `KP_IV`), which leads to a reuse of key/IV pairs for multiple encryptions with the same key and is a vulnerability.
For completeness, note that halving the key size with `key.size() / 2` is actually not required.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know about about the terminology to be able to fix this by myself. It would be great if you can provide the final source code. Thanks very much

Comment: @David - Here https://codefile.io/f/rzShxqzhpv you can find a code that is successfully executed on my machine (encrypting a text file, decrypting the encrypted file). You need to adjust the paths.

Comment: still not working for me!
>decrypt.exe
Original Data: xxxxxxxx
Error: CryptEncrypt failed with error code 234
Encryption failed!
Error: CryptDecrypt failed with error code 2148073476
Decryption failed!

>cat c:\\temp\\text.txt
ABZ